# how to send the text to modal and model text to main screen?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

Could you please tell me how to send the text to modal view and model view text to main screen? In my demo I have one text field and button. I need to send input text to modal and on modal I have one textfield and button I need to send that input field value on main screen. How we comunicate the main screen to modal screen. I need to send data to modal and get data from modal in angular
here is my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNabez

```
var app =angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic']);
app.controller('cntr',function($scope,$http,$ionicModal){
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalFirst = modal;
  });
  $scope.openmodel=function(){
   // alert('d');
    $scope.modalFirst.show()
  }


})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the variables in scope for that and then bind it
i have edited your codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVJGxm

**HTML:**

```
 <html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="cntr">

   <ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">load data before modal show</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content scroll="false">

     <button ng-click="openmodel()">send data on popup screen </button>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Say Something" ng-model="input.saySomething"/>
      <h1>{{item.text}}</h1>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
   <script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">departure</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <h1>naveen+{{input.saySomething}}</h1>
       <input type="text" ng-model="item.text">
      <button>send to main screen</button>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
    </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
var app =angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic']);
app.controller('cntr',function($scope,$http,$ionicModal){
  $scope.item={};
  $scope.input={};
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalFirst = modal;
  });
  $scope.openmodel=function(){
   // alert('d');
    $scope.modalFirst.show()
  }


})
```

Comment: @f5ed could you explain more

Comment: well you have binding to the inputs are {{input.saySomething}} so it refers to an property saySomething in an object input ng-model will create variables/property if not available in scope but it can't create object and its property (i think) so you need to define the object for that in the scope